Interpreting results with a cox test
I am trying to compare 2 non nested models using coxtest from lmtest library. Lamentably I can not find some explanation  about the results from this test.
My first goal was use anova(model1, model2) to compare 2 test but I failed because I use different database (only different observation number: 485 vs 500 obs, but same data origin).
Some web page describe that this test verify if one model its better than other. But in my 2nd and 3rd example not verify this. Or only test if both models are differents?
Probably I miss something or I am doing something wrong ...
Here I test same model, same database but differents observations number:
library(lmtest)

Model 1: Gasto ~ log(Ingreso)
Model 2: Gasto ~ log(Ingreso)
                    Estimate Std. Error     z value  Pr(>|z|)    
fitted(M1) ~ M2   -0.037  0.0033982 -1.1011e+01 < 2.2e-16 ***
fitted(M2) ~ M1 -253.894  0.0000885 -2.8705e+06 < 2.2e-16 ***
    ---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
Warning messages:
1: In coxtest(mod4, mod5) : models fitted on different subsets
2: In coxtest(mod4, mod5) : different dependent variables specified

Why both models are significants? differents in what sense? M1 different from M2? or better? M2 different from M1? or better?
Here I test different model, same database.
I change the name of gasto only to verify if model order change results in the table, example:
coxtest(mod3, mod4):
    
Model 1: Gasto3 ~ Ingreso
Model 2: Gasto ~ log(Ingreso)
                            Estimate Std. Error     z value Pr(>|z|)    
fitted(M1) ~ M2   -0.075   0.218506     -0.3454   0.7298    
fitted(M2) ~ M1 -209.031   0.010401 -20097.4191   <2e-16 ***
            ---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
Warning messages:
1: In coxtest(mod3, mod4) : models fitted on different subsets
2: In coxtest(mod3, mod4) : different dependent variables specified

> Cox test
        
coxtest(mod4, mod3):
    
Model 1: Gasto ~ log(Ingreso)
Model 2: Gasto3 ~ Ingreso
Estimate Std. Error     z value Pr(>|z|)    
fitted(M1) ~ M2   -0.134   0.210933     -0.6361   0.5247    
fitted(M2) ~ M1 -253.604   0.012717 -19942.2191   <2e-16 ***
            ---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
Warning messages:
1: In coxtest(mod4, mod3) : models fitted on different subsets
2: In coxtest(mod4, mod3) : different dependent variables specified

In the last result I expected that p-value was in the first result not the last result, because I change order of model.
Could someone give some advice or explain better?

some similar questions with answer
